# Git Repository design questions

Tags: design, git, repository

I have following hierarchy of topics I am working on

DataStructure

- Linked List
- Array
- Stacks
- Tree

Enterprise Apps

- EJB
- JMS

Android App

- Games
- Productivity Apps

My question is how can I best organize it into GIT (Gitlab or BitBucket). Should I create one repository for DataStructure or individual for LinkedList, etc.

Similarly if I have multiple Android apps, should I create one for each app?

Comment: Are you working on an application ? libraries ? a book on these subjects ?

Answer (score 1):

For your applications, create one repository for each. This is so that your commits only relate to changes of that specific application. This will allow you to keep better track of your versions.

For your Data Structures, perhaps you could create one repository for all of them (and consider that repository a "foundational component" library).

Comment: That will make life easier for DataStructure components, as they are related.  But if I create one repository for all Data Structure components, could I grant access to only selected components ?  For example, I am trying to create sample codes for different ADTs for tutorial purpose. If I want to give access to only LinkedList component, can I do that ?